# Using the appropriate method of the String object

Tags: javascript, string, methods

I have an assignment for school regarding using the appropriate method of the string object to search for a string within a string. Most of the page is provided for us. Our job is to create the code that will do the search. The objectives are as follows, Use an appropriate method of the String object to determine whether the string exists within the search string. Next, if the string is found, alert the user with the index position at which the string was found. Finally, if the string is not found, provide the user with an appropriate message. At this time, I know that the `match()` method is not what they are asking for so I will change it to the `test()` method. Having said that, I can't figure out why when clicking the search button, nothing happens, not even an error or anything.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Lesson 6 Application Project A</title>

  <script language="JavaScript" type=text/javascript>
    <!--
    /***************************************************************************** 
    The placeholders sub and string are used to pass as arguments the 
    user's entry into the text box and the textarea.  The variable where 
    is assigned the result of a method which returns the index (integer) 
    of the first occurence of sub (the string the program is searching for).
    Start the search at the beginning of string (the text that is being searched).
    Since the string is zero based, add 1 is to get the correct position of sub.
    *****************************************************************************/
        
        
       function search(sub, string) {
        var where = string;
        var look = new RegExp(sub);
  
  
  
  if (look === true){
      alert("Your index position is: " + look);
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Your string was not found!");
  }
         
  



    }
        document.write(look.search(where));
       
     //-->
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h3>CIW JavaScript Specialist</h3>
  <hr />

  <form name="myForm">
    <p>
      <strong>Look for:</strong>
      <input type="text" name="what" size="20" />
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>in this string:</strong>
      <textarea name="toSearch" rows="4" cols="30" wrap="virtual">
      </textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="search(myForm.what.value, myForm.toSearch.value);" />
    </p>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look up `String.indexOf` for a better solution

Comment: Came here to say what @synthet1c said -- `String.indexOf` is probably a better choice.

Comment: Look at the developer console. It will have an error message for you.

Comment: I moved your code into a snippet. Click "Run code snippet" and then click "Search". What does the console say? There is certainly at least 1 error.  Hints `look` is not a string; `where/g` is what? Read through methods of [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String); see which one will do what you want.  Scanning through the available methods is a normal thing to do when becoming familiar with a new language/API. You may also want to look at [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: So update, I now know that what I need to be using is search() as they are asking for the return of the index position of the substring. That being said I still can't figure out how to search for the substring and display the index position or a message that says it is not there.